# Having issues with adding content from ObservableList to TableView FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

I am having difficulty with adding content to TableView
here is the code. I think I need to change something with TableView-elemnt..
I dont know Im stuck. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you.

FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?> 
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?> 
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?> 
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?> 
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?> 
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?> 
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?> 
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?> 
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="429.0"
    prefWidth="677.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="registerapp.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16"
            minWidth="69" />
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796"
            layoutX="-1.0" prefHeight="429.0" prefWidth="745.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="Anchorepane" minHeight="0.0"
                    minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="427.0" prefWidth="247.0">
                    <children>
                        <Label fx:id="lable" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0"
                            prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="103.0" text="Register Details"
                            textFill="#0080ff">
                            <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <JFXTextField fx:id="firstName" layoutX="14.0"
                            layoutY="63.0" onAction="#firstName" promptText="First Name" />
                        <JFXTextField fx:id="lastName" layoutX="14.0"
                            layoutY="111.0" onAction="#lastName" promptText="Last Name" />
                        <JFXTextField fx:id="address" layoutX="14.0"
                            layoutY="162.0" onAction="#address" promptText="Address" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="contractBox" layoutX="14.0"
                            layoutY="226.0" onAction="#contractBox" prefHeight="25.0"
                            prefWidth="135.0" promptText="Duration of Contract" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="speedBox" layoutX="14.0"
                            layoutY="273.0" onAction="#speedBox" prefHeight="25.0"
                            prefWidth="135.0" promptText="Internet Speed" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="flowBox" layoutX="14.0"
                            layoutY="323.0" onAction="#flowBox" prefHeight="25.0"
                            prefWidth="135.0" promptText="Internet Flow" />
                        <JFXButton fx:id="registerBtn" layoutX="117.0"
                            layoutY="388.0" onAction="#registerBtn" prefHeight="25.0"
                            prefWidth="69.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0080ff;"
                            text="Register" textFill="#fffbfb" />
                        <JFXButton fx:id="clearAll" layoutX="14.0"
                            layoutY="388.0" onAction="#clearAll"
                            style="-fx-background-color:
#0080ff;" text="Clear All"
                            textFill="#fffafa" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0"
                    prefHeight="427.0" prefWidth="495.0">
                    <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="tabela" prefHeight="429.0"
                            prefWidth="519.0">
                            <columns>
                                <TableColumn prefWidth="81.0" text="First Name" />
                                <TableColumn prefWidth="79.0" text="Last Name" />
                                <TableColumn prefWidth="123.0" text="Address" />
                                <TableColumn prefWidth="55.0" text="DC" />
                                <TableColumn prefWidth="101.0" text="Internet Speed" />
                                <TableColumn prefWidth="79.0" text="Internet Flow" />
                            </columns>

                        </TableView>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

---

FXMLDocumentController:

```
package application;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField firstName;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField lastName;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField address;
    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<String> contractBox;
    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<String> speedBox;
    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<String> flowBox;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton registerBtn;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton clearAll;

    @FXML
    TableView<Person> tabela = new TableView<>();

    ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList();

    Person person;

    public FXMLDocumentController()// ***
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        person = new Person();

        firstName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.firstNameProperty());
        lastName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.lastNameProperty());
        address.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.addressProperty());

        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("", "One Year", "Two Year");
        ObservableList<String> list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList("", "2Mbit", "5Mbit", "10Mbit", "20Mbit",
                "50Mbit", "100Mbit");
        ObservableList<String> list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList("", "1GB", "5GB", "10GB", "100GB", "Flat");

        contractBox.setItems(list);
        speedBox.setItems(list1);
        flowBox.setItems(list2); // ***

        contractBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String selected = contractBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                person.contractBoxProperty().set(selected);
            }

        }); // ***

        speedBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String selected = speedBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                person.speedBoxProperty().set(selected);
            }

        }); // ***

        flowBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String selected = flowBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                person.flowBoxProperty().set(selected);
            }

        });

    }

    @FXML
    private void firstName(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void lastName(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void address(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void contractBox(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void speedBox(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void flowBox(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void registerBtn(ActionEvent event) {
        if (person.isValid()) {
            persons = tabela.getItems();

            persons.add(new Person(firstName.getText(), lastName.getText(), address.getText(), contractBox.getValue(),
                    speedBox.getValue(), flowBox.getValue()));// ***
            // ***
            tabela.setItems(persons);

        } else {
            StringBuilder errMsg = new StringBuilder();

            ArrayList<String> errList = person.errorsProperty().get();
            for (String errList1 : errList)
                errMsg.append(errList1);

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Person can not register!");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText(errMsg.toString());
            alert.showAndWait();
            errList.clear();
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void clearAll(ActionEvent event) {

        person.firstNameProperty().set("");
        person.lastNameProperty().set("");
        person.addressProperty().set("");

        contractBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        flowBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        speedBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }

}
```

PersonClass:

```
package registerapp;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty; 
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty; 
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty; 
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", "");
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", "");
    private final StringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "addres", "");
    private final StringProperty contractBox = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "contractBox", "");
    private final StringProperty speedBox = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "speedBox", "");
    private final StringProperty flowBox = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "flowBox", "");

    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(String firstName)
    {   this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
    {   this.firstName.set(firstName);  this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String contractBox, String speedBox, String flowBox)
    {   this.firstName.set(firstName);  this.lastName.set(lastName);    this.address.set(address);  this.contractBox.set(contractBox);  this.speedBox.set(speedBox);    this.flowBox.set(flowBox);
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {   return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {   this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty()
    {   return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {   return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {   this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty()
    {   return lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {   return address.get();
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {   this.address.set(address);
    }

    public StringProperty addressProperty()
    {   return address;
    }

    public String getContract()
    {   return contractBox.get();
    }

    public void setContract(String contractBox)
    {   this.contractBox.set(contractBox);
    }

    public StringProperty contractBoxProperty()
    {   return contractBox;
    }

    public String getSpeed()
    {   return speedBox.get();
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speedBox)
    {   this.speedBox.set(speedBox);
    }

    public StringProperty speedBoxProperty()
    {   return speedBox;
    }

    public String getFlow()
    {   return flowBox.get();
    }

    public void setFlow(String flowBox)
    {   this.flowBox.set(flowBox);
    }

    public StringProperty flowBoxProperty()
    {   return flowBox;
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<ArrayList<String>> errorList = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "errorList", new ArrayList<>());

    public ObjectProperty<ArrayList<String>> errorsProperty()
    {   return errorList;
    }

    public boolean isValid()
    {   boolean isValid = true;

    if(firstName.get() != null && firstName.get().equals(""))   {
        errorList.getValue().add("First name can't be empty!");
        isValid = false;    }   if(lastName.get().equals(""))   {
        errorList.getValue().add("Last name can't be empty!");
        isValid = false;    }   if(address.get().equals(""))    {
        errorList.getValue().add("Address can't be empty!");
        isValid = false;    }

    return isValid;
    }

}
```

If you copy this code you will need to add to library this file:  jfoenix-8.0.1

Here is the download link ---- https://ufile.io/ineld

Thanks

Comment: Please read up on how to [format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in your questions.

Comment: As far as I can tell you have no cell value factories registered with your table columns. Consequently, there is no way for the cells in the column to be able to determine what data they are supposed to display. Have a look at some basic tutorials: [this one](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) is quite popular.